# How do I center an image provided as an ASP.NET image control?

Tags: asp.net, css, image, panel

The question is pretty straightforward. I have an `<asp:Image>` which lives in an `<asp:Panel>`. My goal is to provide a very basic "print preview" where either left, center, or right alignment is selected. The panel represents the full print area (a sheet of 8.5" x 11" paper) and the image inside is the area that will actually get printed. The full code is this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server"
    BackColor="Black"
    BorderStyle="Inset" 
    Width="425px"
    Height="550px" >
    <asp:Image runat="server" Height="425px" ImageAlign="" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I set the `ImageUrl` property in the code behind, no problems there. If I want to align the image all the way to the left or right, I can just specify `ImageAlign="[Left|Right]"`. However, I haven't been able to find a way to *center* the image in the panel. I've tried all the different ImageAlign values and none of them seem to do what I want. Am I SOL here? If I have to, I can alter the CSS class for the image or panel but I couldn't figure out anything successful with that approach either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what if you use panel HorizontalAlign="Center" property.......

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel2" HorizontalAlign="Center">
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

in your panel tag (which becomes a div client side) just add this attribute:

```
CssStyle="text-align:center;"
```

Though that would center EVERYTHING within that panel.

Perhaps just set the CssStyle of the image to a hardcoded left-margin?  If your goal is a fixed width print preview, this should be ok.

Comment: Only one way to find out ;) ... I would think you would just leave the ImageAlign propery out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Panel CSS Property:

```
CssStyle="alignCenter"
```

CSS:

```
.alignCenter
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either use inline style sheet or external style sheet to accomplish this and add your css code in it